# Converting csv to json

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, csv

I am trying to convert multiple rows of CSV file to single row  stored in a variable. That will be used later as a part of json for rest API.

My csv file looks like:

```
Key     Value
Key1   Value1
Key2   Value2
Key3   Value3
```

I need an output string like:

```
Json= "key1":"Value1","key2":"Value2","key3":"Value3"
```

As of now I have tried this:

if you go to csv in docs python, the example is:

```
import csv
with open('file.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
csvReader = csv.reader(csvfile)
for row,column in csvReader:
    Json= '"'+row+'":'+column+'",'
Print json
```

But this is not giving me the desired output. The output has comma in the last. Like

```
Json= "key1":"Value1","key2":"Value2","key3":"Value3",
```

Comment: Technically, that looks like a TSV and not a CSV.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. There are multiple issues with your code example, like wrong/missing indentation, you have tagged with python-3.x while your print misses parentheses, etc. Please make sure to provide properly readable code examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `json` library

Try like below

```
import json

csv_dict = dict()

for row,column in csvReader:
    csv_dict[row] = column

dump_variable = json.dumps(csv_dict)
print(dump_variable)
```

Comment: This is the exact format what I want.. but the problem here is I want this data into some variable and I put this variable in a further dumps like: Json= "key1":"Value1","key2":"Value2","key3":"Value3" but now I will use just this json variable like json.dumps("id":json) please suggest how to do this

Comment: well `csv_dict` is variable. Use it further accordingly. Go through tutorials to know how to access dictionary keys and values via for loop.

Comment: But, when I print(csv_dict) I get different output from the expected one.

Comment: oh.i misunderstood. store `json.dumps(csv_dict)` in a variable and use it further as above. remember it is JSON text. You may need to do some coding based on your need

Comment: I tried json.dumps("I'd":dump_variable) but getting an error "TypeError: Object of type 'set' is not JSON serializable"

Comment: `dump_variable` is string and your question is unclear; what I understand is you want to access key, values from the JSON. you can either use dictionary `csv_dict` or use `json.loads` on json string to convert JSON back to dictionary and use. Saying that this answer has more than enough help on how to code. I suggest you to go through **tutorials**.

Answer (score 1):

Only small change needed:

```
import csv
with open('file.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    csvReader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row,column in csvReader:
        json= '"'+row+'":'+column+'",'
print json[:-1]
```

will remove the last comma and output:

```
Json= "key1":"Value1","key2":"Value2","key3":"Value3"
```

Comment: Indentation after the with-statement is missing.

Comment: @Prateek But it is what the author asked for, he might add {} or [] in part of his code.

Comment: It removes all the commas :( not the last one

Answer (score 1):

Using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv',sep=',') # sep can be \s+ if multiple spaces
jsonstr = df.set_index('Key')['Value'].to_dict()

print(jsonstr)
```

Prints

```
{'Key1': 'Value1', 'Key2': 'Value2', 'Key3': 'Value3'}
```