# How to convert csv to string?

Tags: json, python-3.x, csv

I have a csv file like:

```
Key     Value
Key1   Value1
Key2   Value2
Key3   Value3
```

And I want it to be converted in a string like:

```
Variable= "key1":"Value1","key2":"Value2","key3":"Value3"
```

Please suggest how can I do it. I will be using this variable later on to do a put on rest API like below:

```
body=Json.dumps("id":somedata, "value":{Variable})
urllib.request.Request(url=some url, data=body)
```

Where somedata is another variable which I want to do put on rest API.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting csv to json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49371868/converting-csv-to-json)

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of your previous question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you file is called `f.csv`, you can use the following:

```
import json
json.dumps({k: v for k,v in (p.split() for p in open('f.csv').read().split('\n')[:-1])})
```

giving:

```
'{"Key1": "Value1", "Key2": "Value2", "Key": "Value", "Key3": "Value3"}'
```